# How can I apply a style to all buttons?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

How and where do I create a style that gives all button controls that have resource blue (yellow border, blue background)?

Can it also be added to a texbox as well?

Is there a centralized place, since I would want this style to be able affect buttons in different pages in my app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In these cases you may use `Styles`:

- You are going to apply same properties (or members) on several controls of a type
- You are going to make save good and desired state of a type and use it later.

You can add this `Style` in control's resources or `ResourceDictionaries` like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>
```

If you define `x:key`, then you should explicitly say that which button follows your style (e.g. `<Button Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyleKey}">`) otherwise your style will be automatically apply on buttons.

**EDIT:** Add a **ResourceDictionary** (named `myStyles.xaml`) to your project (In a folder named `MyResource`). Here is the code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in your `App.xaml` add this:

```
<Application x:Class="WPFApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResource/myStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: How do I add it to ResourceDictionaries?

Comment: To edit any controls template (the whole template!) just select the control either in the designer, or in the document outline window, right click and select edit template. As Hossein said, removing the x:key attribute sets the style on all controls of that targettype. How-to by images here: http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/07/22/example-winrtmetro-app-how-to-edit-default-template-in-visual-studio-2012-and-blend/